# Net (Mooore - Smith) Convergence question

Tags: general-topology, analysis, nets

Give topological space $(X,\tau)$, $E \subset X$, $\{x_{\alpha}\} \subset E, x\in E$ and $(E,\tau_{E})$ is subset topological space of $(X,\tau)$.

I have proved that: If $x_{\alpha} \xrightarrow{(E,\tau_{E})} x$ then $x_{\alpha} \xrightarrow{(X,\tau)} x$.

(Here is my proof)

Give $V$ is neighborhood of $x$ in $(X,\tau)$.

There exist $G \in \tau$ that $x \in G \subset V$.

Therefore, $x \in G \cap E \subset V \cap E$.

So, $V \cap E$ is a neighborhood of $x$ in $(E,\tau_{E})$.

Since $x_{\alpha} \xrightarrow{(E,\tau_{E})} x$ then exist $\alpha_{o}$ that if $\forall \alpha \ge \alpha_{o} \Rightarrow x_{\alpha} \in V \cap E \subset V$

Therefore, $x_{\alpha} \xrightarrow{(X,\tau)} x$.

**I wonder that the converse is correct or not?**

Comment: Are you assuming $E$ is closed or open in $X$?

Comment: @Keen-ameteur The lecture i have read just give $E$ is a subset of $X$ (don't give $E$ is closed or open).

Comment: The converse is true  Why not prove it?  This  is a **characterization** of the subspace topology $\tau_E$ for a subset $E$ of a topological space $(X,\tau)$:  For any net $x_\alpha$ in $E$ and any point $x \in E$, we have $x_\alpha \to x$ according to $\tau_E$ **if and only if** $x_\alpha \to x$ according to $\tau$.

Comment: @GEdgar Can you hint the way to prove it? I have tried but i failed.

Comment: Let $U$ be in $\tau_E$ containing $x$. What can you say about $U$?

Comment: @HennoBrandsma There exist $G \in \tau$ that $U= E \cap G$.

Comment: Indeed and $x \in G$ of course. Now use that $x_\alpha \to x$ in $(X,\tau)$.

Comment: @HennoBrandsma Thank you, I forgot that $G$ open contain $x$ is also a neighborhood of $x$.

Comment: The fact that the equivalence **characterises** the subspace topology can be shown from "the subspace topology is the minimal topology that makes $i: E \to X$ continuous".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The forward proof is correct, though somewhat verbose.

You can also just note that $i(x)=x$ as a map from $(E,\tau_E) \to (X, \tau)$ is continuous by definition of the subspace topology, and so preserves net convergence; i.e. the same net in the large space has the same limit.

The converse is similar: if $x_\alpha \to x$ in $(X,\tau)$ with all $x_\alpha$ and $x$ in $E$, let $O \ni x$ be open in $E$, so $O = O' \cap E$ with $O'$ open in $X$ and we note $x \in O'$ so some tail of the net sits inside $O'$, and so inside $O=O'\cap E$ as well. Hence $x_\alpha \to x$ in $(E,\tau_E)$ too.